# Derivative of a multivariable function with respect to another multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I need to compute the derivative of a function $M=M(R,\theta)$ depending on two variables $R, \theta$ with respect to another function $H=H(R,\theta)$ of the same variables. I know the result, but I cannot retrace its computation.

Here is my functions:
$$M(R,\theta)=m_0 R^{\beta} \theta$$
$$H(R,\theta)=h_0 R^{\beta \delta} h(\theta)$$
where $m_0, h_0$ are constant parameters, $h(\theta)$ is a given function of the variable $\theta$ only and the relation $\beta \delta =\beta + \gamma$ is known.

I want to compute $\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}$, so I did it this way:

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}=\frac{\partial M}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial H} + \frac{\partial M}{\partial R}\frac{\partial R}{\partial H}$$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial \theta}=m_0 R^{\beta}$$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial R}=m_0 \beta R^{\beta-1} \theta$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta} && \frac{\partial H}{\partial R} \\
\frac{\partial M}{\partial \theta} && \frac{\partial M}{\partial R} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
h_0 R^{\beta \delta} h'(\theta) && h_0 \beta  \delta R^{\beta \delta -1} h(\theta) \\
m_0 R^{\beta} && m_0 \beta R^{\beta -1} \theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
thus (by inversion of this matrix)

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial H} && \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial M} \\
\frac{\partial R}{\partial H} && \frac{\partial R}{\partial H}
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{h_0 m_0 \beta R^{\beta \delta +\beta -1}(\theta h'(\theta)-\delta h(\theta))}
\begin{pmatrix}
m_0 \beta R^{\beta -1} \theta && -h_0 \beta \delta R^{\beta \delta -1} h(\theta) \\
-m_0 R^{\beta} && h_0 R^{\beta \delta} h'(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I end up with the result $\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}=0$, while instead I should obtain
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}=\frac{m_0}{h_0} R^{-\gamma} \frac{(1-\theta^2+2\beta \theta^2)}{2\beta \delta \theta h(\theta)+(1-\theta^2)h'(\theta)}$$

Where is my error?

Comment: Nice first question. Welcome to MSE!